# Error while Index creation using nodejs in Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using npm elasticsearch, in that getting an error like this

> client.index is not a function

here is my code

```
    encryptObj = enpyt.encrypt(function(encrypted){
         client.index({ 
            index: 'collectionnew3
            id: '101',
            type: 'collectiontype3',
            body: {
              "username": "postgres",
              "pswrd": encrypted,

            }
          },function(err,resp,status) {
                console.log(resp);
         })
      })
```

Any idea why am I getting this?

Comment: How are you getting client?, the error is because it doesn't have **index** as a function. Could you show how are you getting client?

Comment: @Hosar I used to to export the client using exports.client its not worked so I used module.exports to export the client in my main.js now problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, it seems that `client` is not properly instantiated.

Example to instantiate an Elasticsearch client in node.js:

```js
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: "http://localhost:9200",
    apiVersion: "2.3"
});
```

Update `host` and `apiVersion` with your configuration.

Comment: ,yes as you said the client is not instantiated properly because I made mistake while importing the client from another file now I used module.export to export the client